# How to minimize the sum of all errors in all grid with dynamic programming?

Tags: dynamic-programming

Given n points in a 3D space. Each point can be represented as (x_i, y_i, z_i).
Now we can split the x-axis into m continuous intervals and so as the y-axis, and we get m*n grids.
For each grid, we define the error as `sum(z_i - z^{bar})^2`, where `z^{bar}` is the average value of z in each grid.

The object is to minimize the total error of all the grids, and further more, plus the number of grids.

So how to solve it with dynamic programming?

Comment: minimizing the total error and minimizing the number of regions are two conflicting objectives (increasing the number of regions obviously allows to decrease the total error, and vice versa). Consequently, you need to state your objective more clearly. Do you want to minimize the total error, under a budget constraint for the number of regions? Do you want to minimize the number of regions, under a budget constraint for the total error? Do you want to minimize a weighted sum of the total error and number of regions?

Comment: Thanks to reply. I have noticed that the total objective is the total error plus the number of grids.